# How to prevent Rails from picking the same random name again?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails 4 application I have this controller action that generate a number of sample `projects` so the `user` can play with it:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

  def generate_samples
    100.times do
      p = current_user.projects.build(
        :name         => random_name,
        :hourly_rate  => random_hourly_rate
      p.save!
    end
    flash[:success] = "Sample projects created."
  end

end
```

Since my `Project` model will only accept new records with unique names, the above function breaks if the same `random_name` gets picked twice within one function call. How can this be prevented?

Comment: append them to array before saving to database, check if name already is in an array, if true get a new one etc

Comment: Where do you get random_name from?

Comment: Have the method `random_name` do what it says. You haven't supplied this method, so no idea how it works. But it is clearly failing to provide a random name. Either it is badly named, or it isn't working well. :)

Comment: For real names look at the faker gem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Either have your function check if the name picked already exists, and repeat, or use something like an UUID where the risk of picking two times the same id is almost 0:

```
name: SecureRandom.uuid
```